# Combining dependencies and values in the constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

I often face a problem of having a class that needs both a dependency and some string value to be initialized. For instance consider the following code:

```
public class CustomerService
{
   public CustomerService(ITcpConnection connection, string realm)
   {
   }
}
```

The problem with it is that it's not easy get that out of the DI container because of the additional string parameter. What are the best ways to fix this issue? These are the way I can think of:

1. Initialize method (It's not good enough as it provides the temporal coupling by Mark Seeman's definition and I agree that it's not a very good way)
2. Abstract factory (I don't really need one extra layer of indirection because the parameter is a configuration and I know it at the time I do the configuration)
3. Use as in the example and register the instance of the class in DI container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixing primitive configuration values and (service) dependencies in the same constructor can best be avoided. They complicate the DI configuration, and often lead to an unreadable and fragile [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

Do the following instead:

**Option 1: Abstract that configuration value**

When the same configuration value is injected into multiple classes, there's often an abstraction missing. A good example of this is the injection of a `string connectionString` value into all repositories. In this case the application likely lacks an `IConnectionFactory` abstraction (or something similar). Instead of injecting the connection string into many classes, the connection string should be injected into the `IConnectionFactory` implementation (that probably only takes that connection string as its constructor argument) and let other services depend on `IConnectionFactory` instead of `string`. This way those services don't have to deal with the creation of connections; the connection factory can do this.

**Option 2: Wrap the configuration value into configuration type**

Primitive types cause ambiguity when it comes to resolving types. That injected `string`, is that a file path or a connection string? That `int` you are injecting, is that the number of retries to do, or the minimum age for customers to buy items?

To prevent the ambiguity, it is good to wrap all configuration values of a class into its own configuration type, even if the class requires just one value. Take for instance at this `SqlUnitOfWorkSettings` that wraps a `TimeSpan`.

```cs
public sealed class SqlUnitOfWorkSettings
{
    public readonly TimeSpan ConnectionTimeout;

    public SqlUnitOfWorkSettings(TimeSpan connectionTimeout)
    {
        this.ConnectionTimeout = connectionTimeout;
    }
}
```

Instead of depending on `TimeSpan`, the `SqlUnitOfWork` can now depend on `SqlUnitOfWorkSettings` instead:

```cs
public sealed class SqlUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly SqlUnitOfWorkSettings settings;

    public SqlUnitOfWork(SqlUnitOfWorkSettings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }
}
```

The use of the new configuration class simplifies registration in your DI Container, because of the lack of ambiguity:

```cs
container.RegisterInstance(
    new SqlUnitOfWorkSettings(connectionTimeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
container.Register<IUnitOfWork, SqlUnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

**Option 3: Create a sub type**

In case the use of configuration classes is not an option (for instance, because you can't change the source code) you can derive a sub type that is placed inyour Composition Root and defines the proper constructor and register that sub type instead:

```cs
public class MyService : SomeExternalService
{
    public MyService(ISomeDependency dep) : base(dep, "My Config Value") { }
}

// Registration
container.Register<IService, MyService>();
```

Comment: In your approach "Abstract that configuration value" you will still need to create an instance of the factory and then register an instance, right? Which is almost the same as in my example. The other two options will create a [Temporal Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/), won't they?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Another way is to directly inject the adapter object. I have once asked it in code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25161/handle-static-objects-using-custom-adapter. It is similiar with Steven's "Abstract that configuration value" but more direct.

Comment: @Steven: I agree it's nothing wrong in registering the factory but then I can register my class itself the same way :) But anyway thanks for help